# Constraints for new forces or fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, forces, particle-physics, resource-recommendations, interactions

There is this argument that any new forces of nature or any new interactions would have very small gap of space left in the experimental space or parameter. The argument being that for every force, there is a particle and a field, and virtual particles. And the virtual particles can affect behavior of particles (for example, the electron moment of the muon) or mass of the Higgs. Can anyone give a reference of exactly this thing about the constraints and the small gap left for new forces of nature or field?

Answer (score 0):

The [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics is based on the three known forces and is validated within experimental errors, except for some specific experimental observations, as for example baryon asymmetry
BUT research is going on beyond the standard model, theoretically, and the new theories do involve new forces. For example [GUTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory) (references in the link) were of the first proposals . The whole point of continuing particle research experiments is to find out if these new theories that embed the standard model for lower energies, are correct.

The *small gap left for new forces of nature or field?* can be found in the proposals for these  new theories. I do not think a separate study would exist.

Comment: I mean, is it not the mass of the Higgs or other masses were the results of effects of virtual particles of all existing particles and forces? Such that any new particles can affect it (forces outside of GUT)? I just want details of this very sensitive balance. Or maybe the mass of the Higgs or others already include all contribution from all unknown forces of nature?